# Django - CurrentUserField

Tags: django, models

I was just exploring http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1132 I am receiving 'undefined' error while using 'models.CurrentUserField' . Is this supported by Django 1.2.3?

Comment: What is undefined? What is the error? Have you actually applied the patch in that ticket? I'd be surprised if it applies at all, given that it's five years old.

Comment: It seems to be this patch won't fit to the current version. Do we have any patches which can be applied to the version 1.2.3?